# Lost all progress in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I opened the Pokemon GO app to play. It tried logging me in, but it said it failed to log in. There was an option to retry with a different account. I clicked on it, and I typed in my username and password for the same account as last time. When I got in to play, I had no Pokemon or eggs. My level bar was still up to where it was, but it didn't tell me what level I was currently on. Can someone help?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Nice first question. Clearly written with some details.

Comment: A screenshot showing your level with 0 Pokemon would solidify this question

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure it's fixed by now but it's a glitch I get sometimes. I just refresh the app and everything should be fine, if not keep refreshing until it's back to normal.